# Run cron service when docker build

Tags: php, docker, cron, docker-compose, docker-container

I have in my docker file :

```
RUN apt-get -y install cron
RUN cron
COPY symfony.cron /var/spool/cron/crontabs/www-data
RUN chown www-data:crontab /var/spool/cron/crontabs/www-data

CMD ["start.sh"]
```

And in my start.sh :

```
echo "+ start cron service"
service cron start
```

All good, the problem is that crons are not running, and is strange because when I go to the docker container and I do `service cron status` I get `[ ok ] cron is running.`
 so all good. And when I try to execute one command, is executed well. And when I do `crontab -u www-data -l` I get the liste with all the crons. So all is good at this point. But the crons are not executed anymore, so I don't understand the problem, maybe some permissions or I don't know. Please help me !!! Thx in advance and sorry for my english.

Any ideas please

Answer (score 1):

You should broadly assume commands like `service start` don’t work in Docker.  Just run the program you’re trying to run directly.  Make sure it starts as a foreground process.

```
CMD ["crond", "-f"]
```

(If your main container script runs a `service start` command, and that command exits, and the main container script exits, then the container will exit, which isn’t what you want.  If `service` is backed by systemd or another init system, your container won’t be running that.)